# where to call invalidate() for animation purpose?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-animation, ondraw, invalidation

I am programming a simple game and has to draw animation on the screen and currently calling `invalidate()` method from within `onDraw()`. I simply wish to periodically update my canvas.

I would like to move the `invalidate()` call somewhere else as calling within `onDraw()` is rather bad. However, my target platform is android gingerbread and I probably can't utilize those methods which involve multithreading.

Is there anyway to setup a timer outside of `onDraw()` which `invalidate()` if the time lapse interval meets my desire without involving multithreading?

Answer (score 1):

> I probably can't utilize those methods which involve multithreading.

That's not true. It is not what you need though. If you need to call invalidate periodically on your view, you can use the View's internal handler and its [postDelayed](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#postDelayed(java.lang.Runnable,%20long)) method, to invoke `invalidate()`. The runnable runs on the UI Thread.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be an idea to call invalidate() after an user input?

If you want a timer look to this:
https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html
This method should be viable with your android version.

Comment: it's a game and it's part of the animation.